# How can I replicate this design?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to implement a design that is similar to the [following design](https://photos.app.goo.gl/LkqXdsU37u45EZbA6) in my app.
So I tried to use a `Stack` with `Card` and `ListView` but there is a problem. the problem is that I need to know the size of the elements above the `ListView` to know where to place it, and I need to know the size of the `ListView` to know how much space to reserve for it in the card!
I tried to use the following function:

```dart
Size getSize(GlobalKey key) {
  RenderBox renderBox = key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
  Size size = renderBox.size;
  return size;
}
```

but it can only run after `build` so it is not really usefull
is there a way to make one widget's size depend on another's?

Comment: You should consider using a package like [this one](https://github.com/serenader2014/flutter_carousel_slider)

Comment: I would recommend that you look into [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html), which gives you a `BoxConstraints` object that is the size of the widget which hasn't yet been built.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved the problem. By using [`OverflowBox`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/OverflowBox-class.html) I can avoid the problem that I run into in the first place and get a much simpler and super maintainable solution that is still reactive to changes in my app